# Why is this neomutt one-liner producing an "Address boundary error"

Tags: mutt

I'm trying to learn how to send batch emails. I have `neomutt` configured on my system. I just tried this neomutt one-liner as a test:

```
echo "This is the body." | neomutt -s "Testing mutt" <EMAIL REDACTED>
```

This one-liner produced the following error:

```
fish: Process 12806, “neomutt” “echo "This is the body." | neom…” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

At first, I thought this had something to do with my shell (fish), but I also get an error with the bash shell:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm using `NeoMutt 2019-10-25`.

Is there something wrong with my one-liner?

Comment: The `Segmentation fault` message means that (most likely) the `neomutt` program tried to access an invalid address and crashed.  Does it work if you run it without piping content to it?

Comment: Works OK on NeoMutt 20170113 (1.7.2) on Linux (Debian).